# Angular 2+ Upload File Interceptor Issue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Hello I'm triying to **upload a file** with **Angular to Net Core 2.1 api**.

In my front-end project I configure a global interceptor for Token Authentication.

Authentication works great with other calls, but when I try to POST a FormData and Append an Authentication Header The server sends a "Missing content-type boundary" error. And when I dont append any header It works correctly.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

This is my **Interceptor**:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const userData: string = localStorage.getItem('userData');

        let request = req;

        if (userData != null) {
            const user = JSON.parse(userData);
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${user['_token']}`
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

This is my **Component**:

```
export interface Contract {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  document?: File;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contract',
  templateUrl: './contract.component.html'
})
export class ContractComponent implements OnInit {
  contractForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private api: ContractService
  ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.contractForm = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(0),
      title: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      document: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    });
}


  onAddContract() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', '0');
    formData.append('title', this.contractForm.get('title').value);
    formData.append('document', this.contractForm.get('document').value, this.contractForm.get('title').value);
    this.api.postContract(formData).subscribe(result => {
    });
  }


  handleFileInput(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.contractForm.get('document').setValue(file);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my **Service**:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ContractService {

    API_URL: string = "http://localhost:59976/api"

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


    postContract(contract: FormData) {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
            })
          };

        return this.http.post<Contract>(this.API_URL + '/contratos', contract);
    }
}
```

I made a little example:

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fileupload-interceptor)

Comment: The cloned request is stored in the variabe `request`, but you're sending `req`, the original request. So your interceptor actually does nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that when I did the question, I have the problem yet. thanks for noticing.